# Getting PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed in pyspark when calling UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am using pyspark 2.0. i am getting pickling error for bellow code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import*
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


def getTime():
    timevalue=datetime.now()
    return timevalue

spark.udf.register('Getday', getTime,TimestampType())

def datetostring_conv(datevalue):
    stringvalue=datevalue.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print stringvalue
    intstring=stringvalue[0:4]+stringvalue[5:7]+stringvalue[8:10]
    return intstring

spark.udf.register('IntString',lambda(x):datetostring_conv,StringType())
```

up to this when i am calling

```
spark.sql("select date_add(Getday(),-1)as stringtime").show()
```

i am getting the previous day value as date type but when i am trying to converting it into string avoiding '-'. which is IntString function job I am getting the pickling error

```
spark.sql("select IntString(date_add(GetDay(),1))as stringvalue").show()
```

how could i solve this error

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either call the function:

```
spark.udf.register('IntString', lambda x: datetostring_conv(x), StringType())
```

or pass the function:

```
spark.udf.register('IntString', datetostring_conv, StringType())
```

When you use:

```
lambda x: datetostring_conv
```

you pass an unary function which returns a function:

```
type((lambda x: datetostring_conv)(datetime.now()))
```

```
function
```

hence the exception.

Of course there is no need for an UDF:

```
spark.sql("SELECT date_format(date_add(current_date(), -1), 'YYYYMMdd')")
```

**Notes**:

You shouldn't use parentheses with argument list of lambda expressions. This:

- Has no effect with a single argument.
- With more than one argument:

  - Has a special meaning in Python 2  (tuple argument unpacking).
  - [Is not supported in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I didn't include the argument when registering the function:

```
def find_thresh(wav):
    [some code returning int]

convertUDF = udf(lambda z: find_thresh,IntegerType())
```

when it should have been:

```
convertUDF = udf(lambda z: find_thresh(z),IntegerType())
```

Just in case it helps.